# Alterar String Eixo Y Google Chart

Tags: javascript, google-charts

Utilizo `Google Chart` para gerar gráficos. Tenho um `array` com valores de 1 à 4. Esses valores são do tipo `int`. Preciso mudar a descrição do eixo Y. Para:

1 = Ótimo, 
2 = Bom, 
3 = Regular,
4 = Ruim.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Pergunta', 'Valor 1', 'Valor 2'],
        ['Pergunta 1', 2, 3],
        ['Pergunta 2', 4, 1],
        ['Pergunta 3', 1, 1]
    ]);

    var options = {
        height: 600           

    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('grafico'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: Não entendi qual é a sua dúvida

Comment: Repare no eixo Y, tem o valores de 1, 2, 3 e 4. Eu queria substituir se for possível para: Ótimo, Bom, Regular e Ruim. Que representa os valores de 1 até 4. Entendeu?

Comment: Agora sim. Acho que se você [edit] a pergunta e adicionar esse comentário, ficaria mais fácil para entender.

Comment: Coloquei uma imagem do jeito que quero que fique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O que você busca é a [customização dos Axes](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes).

Em seu caso especificamente, é o vAxis.

Para adequar ao seu exemplo, pasta alterar as opções do gráfico para isso:

```
 var options = {
        height: 600,
        vAxis: {
          title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)',
          ticks: [{v:0, f:"Ótimo 1"},{v:2.5, f:"Bom 2"},{v:5.0, f:"Regular 3"},{v:7.5, f:"Ruim 4"}]
        }        
    };
```

Basta alterar o **v:** para o valor contido no gráfico e o **f:** pelo texto que deseja mostrar.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Pergunta', 'Valor 1', 'Valor 2'],
    ['Pergunta 1', 2, 3],
    ['Pergunta 2', 4, 1],
    ['Pergunta 3', 1, 1]
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 600,
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Rating (scale of 1-10)',
      ticks: [{
        v: 1,
        f: "Ótimo 1"
      }, {
        v: 2,
        f: "Bom 2"
      }, {
        v: 3,
        f: "Regular 3"
      }, {
        v: 4,
        f: "Ruim 4"
      }]
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('grafico'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="grafico"></div>
```

[Veja um exemplo funcional no JsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/4oL0L361/2/)

Comment: Valeu amigo....

Comment: Não to conseguindo colocar as linhas verticais. O que pode ser será?

Comment: @EduardoSantos Não entendi quais linhas você fala. Porém, se a dúvida é diferente desta pergunta, abra outra para ficar mais fácil compreender

Answer (score 3):

Veja se dessa forma funciona.
Para melhor entendimento também pode-se utilizar o JsFiddle para simular o que acontece e assim podermos te ajudar melhor. Na minha cabeça me veio isso por enquanto...

```
var options = {
   height: 600,
   vAxis: {title: "Status", ticks: [{v:1, f:"Ótimo"}, {v:2, f:"Bom"}, {v:3, f:"Regular"}, {v:4, f:"Ruim"}]},
};
```

Comment: Valeu amigo....

Answer (score 2):

Só adicionar esse trecho dentro das `options`:

```
vAxis: {
        ticks: [{v:1, f:"Ótimo 1"},
        {v:2, f:"Bom 2"},
        {v:3, f:"Regular 3"},
        {v:4, f:"Ruim 4"}]
       }
```

Vai ficar assim:

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Pergunta', 'Valor 1', 'Valor 2'],
        ['Pergunta 1', 2, 3],
        ['Pergunta 2', 4, 1],
        ['Pergunta 3', 1, 1]
    ]);

    var options = {
        height: 600,
        vAxis: {
          ticks: [{v:1, f:"Ótimo 1"},
          {v:2, f:"Bom 2"},
          {v:3, f:"Regular 3"},
          {v:4, f:"Ruim 4"}]
        }        
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('grafico'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Veja funcionando no [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ctyoj5r0/1/).

Comment: Exatamente isso, obrigado :)